# JOIN query that returns list of objects of different models?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phalcon

So far I have this code:

```
$list = $this->modelsManager
             ->createBuilder()
             ->columns(array("SeriesList.*", "User.*", "Entry.*"))
             ->from("SeriesList")
             ->join("User")
             ->join("Entry")
             ->andWhere("SeriesList.id = '$id'")
             ->getQuery()
             ->execute();
```

Each row in the "Entry" database is an item that has a id, id of the series list it belongs to, its series id, and what type of series it is. The type of series specifies what table the series id can be found in.

The problem is that I want SeriesList(s) to may contain different types of objects. For example, the SeriesList "Favorites" may contain 3 shows and 4 books, Show and Book being different models which interface with separate tables.

Would I have to keep joining for all the models the list might contain? Or is there a better way?

Comment: How does the 'id of the series list it belongs to' differ from its 'series id'

Comment: @Strawberry SeriesList is a model. Each SeriesList has a name and an id, the id which is referred to as the former in your question. The series id is a slug (I could've used an integer, but I decided to combine the purposes of an primary key id and a slug in order to make things easier) which is a unique primary key for its series, be it a Show or a Book or another series class I would happen to add later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query builder will return a resultset which could be a model itself or a combined model (if you are doing joins etc.). It will not return objects of other models.

What you can do is use the `getRelated()` function to access the relationships from the base model itself.

So if your starting point is `Entry` then you could do something like this:

```
$entries = Entries::find();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    // If series type is X
    if ($entry->seriesType == 'x') {
        $newItem = $entry->getRelated('x');
    } else if ($entry->seriesType == 'y') {
        $newItem = $entry->getRelated('y');
    }
}
```

You can define relationships in your models that will cater for that. The key here is that Phalcon's relationships will relate data from table A to table B straight up and without any "filtering". So if you want to relate `Entries` to `Favorites` if `SeriesList == 'favorite'` you cannot, at least automatically. You will have to do that with code similar to the one above.